# Serving as Vs Serving a

Tags: grammar

I want to write that someone is as a commander

Do I need to write "is serving as a commander" or "is serving a commander"?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't necessarily need the article, but you do need ***as*** in all contexts I can think of that are relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

I hope these examples will clarify the role of the word "as" and of the word "a".

1. *"He is serving as commander of the ship."* This sounds like a man is filling the role of Commander of the Ship.
2. *"He is serving as a commander of the ship."* This sounds like there are several Commanders of the Ship, and a man is one of those commanders.
3. *"He is serving a commander of the ship."* This sounds like a man is a servant and is serving dinner to one of the commanders of the ship.

My guess is that example #1 is what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

How did "serving" butt in?
Here's a better verb:  He commands a ship.

If you really really want to say "commander", here's a weaker sentence:
He is the commander of a ship.

Comment: A person can have the rank "Commander" without being in command of a ship.  In fact, oddly, somebody in command of a ship usually has the rank "Captain", and "Commander" is one rank below that.  @Ar134 may be referring to the rank.